Change terminal command colour in PyCharm
I’m running a fairly current version of PyCharm on Windows 10. It’s an older version of Windows, so I can’t run the very latest PyCharm.
I have chosen a light them, which works well enough until it comes to the Terminal. The terminal, it appears uses PowerShell. The real problem is that commands, such as dir and python appear in yellow. Against a white background.
I’ve tried changing every setting I can find and the only thing that I can’t fix is this yellow colour.
Is there any way of changing this colour? If that involves using cmd instead of PowerShell, that’s also fine, if someone can show me how.

This may or may not answer your question.
You can print colours to terminal with ANSI escape keys.
This alerts the computer to follow a specific colour, background colour, or text formatting. This change colours in terminal via Python code. To
This is the format:
print(\033[code]m")
Here is a complete list of formats:
class ANSI:
    class codes:
        COLOURS = {
            # Text colours
            "PURPLE": "\033[35m",
            "BLUE": "\033[34m",
            "GREEN": "\033[32m",
            "RED": "\033[31m",
            "YELLOW": "\033[33m",
            "BLACK": "\033[30m",
            "CYAN": "\033[36m",
            "GREY": "\033[37m",
            "WHITE": "\033[38m",
            # Bright colours
            "BRIGHT-RED": "\u001b[91m",
            "BRIGHT-GREEN": "\u001b[92m",
            "BRIGHT-YELLOW": "\u001b[93m",
            "BRIGHT-BLUE": "\u001b[94m",
            "BRIGHT-PURPLE": "\u001b[95m",
            "BRIGHT-CYAN": "\u001b[96m",
            "BRIGHT-WHITE": "\u001b[97m",
            "BRIGHT-GREY": "\u001b[90m",
            #Background colours
            "RED-BACKGROUND": "\033[41m",
            "BLUE-BACKGROUND": "\033[44m",
            "GREEN-BACKGROUND": "\033[102m",
            "YELLOW-BACKGROUND": "\033[43m",
            "PURPLE-BACKGROUND": "\033[45m",
            "BLACK-BACKGROUND": "\033[40m",
            "PINK-BACKGROUND": "\033[45m",
            "CYAN-BACKGROUND": "\033[46m",
            "WHITE-BACKGROUND": "\033[8m",
            "GREY-BACKGROUND": "\033[47m",
            #Bright background colours
            "BRIGHT-RED-BACKGROUND": "\033[101m",
            "BRIGHT-GREEN-BACKGROUND": "\033[102m",
            "BRIGHT-YELLOW-BACKGROUND": "\033[103m",
            "BRIGHT-BLUE-BACKGROUND": "\033[104m",
            "BRIGHT-PURPLE-BACKGROUND": "\033[105m",
            "BRIGHT-GREY-BACKGROUND": "\033[100m",
            "BRIGHT-CYAN-BACKGROUND": "\033[106m",
            "BRIGHT-WHITE-BACKGROUND": "\033[107m",
        }
        FORMATS = {
            "BOLD": "\033[1m",
            "ITALIC": "\033[3m",
            "UNDERLINE": "\033[4m",
            "STRIKETHROUGH": "\033[9m",
            "BOXED": "\033[51m",
        }
    class characters:
        CHARACTERS = [
        #     use a .csv file
        ]
# for i in range(1000):
#     print(f"\033[{i}m" + "test")
#     print("\033[0m")
#     i+=1
# print("\033[0m")
# print(ANSI.codes.FORMATS["DOUBLE-UNDERLINE"]+"help")


This may be the only solution. You can change the colours in PowerShell using something like:
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor Black

This is from:
https://superuser.com/questions/676140/how-to-set-colors-in-psreadline-in-powershell#answer-676587
